# Flask Blueprint; No module found named

Tags: flask, importerror, blueprint

I'm trying to get Flask Blueprints running in Docker, but having issues with registering Blueprints correct.

I have the following structure:

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── nginx
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── sites-enabled
│       └── flask_project
└── web
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── app.py
    ├── modules
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── page
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── forms.py
    │       ├── models.py
    │       ├── views.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── static
    │   ├── css
    │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
    │   │   └── main.css
    │   ├── img
    │   └── js
    │       └── bootstrap.min.js
    └── templates
        ├── _base.html
        └── index.html
```

app.py contains:

```
from flask import Flask
from web.modules.page import simple_page

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(simple_page)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print app.url_map
    app.run(debug=True)
```

views.py contains:

```
from flask import Blueprint

simple_page = Blueprint('simple_page', __name__,
                  template_folder='templates')

@simple_page.route('/')
def index():
  return "Hello world"
```

`__init__.py` under page:

```
from web.modules.page.views import simple_page
```

The `__init__.py` files are empty.

The console gives an ImportError: No module named web.modules.page

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I had exact same issue and I solved it by removing project name. So change from web.modules.page.views import simple_page to from modules.page.views import simple_page    And it should work.

Comment: Thanks for this, @Avinash. You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like is structure problem, you can reference from here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-structure-large-flask-applications

The following is my example, hope it can help for you:

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── models
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── js
│   │   ├── img
│   │   └── file
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── index.html
└── master.py
```

**app/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from app.main import main

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)    
    app.register_blueprint(main)

    return app
```

**app/main/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

from app.main import views
```

**master.py**

```
from app import create_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, threaded=True)
```

Comment: This is a completely different folder structure. It does not answer why app is not able to access web.module.page module.